# Axios Get is returning an empty array in my React Component

Tags: axios, get, frontend, hook, react-tsx

Here is my Component where I am need to load data from the backend.

```
import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardFooter,
  Flex,
  Image,
  Spacer,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import CardIcon from "./CardIcon";
import DescriptionText from "./DescriptionText";
import placeholder from "../images/placeholder.jpg";
import useCards, { GauntletCard } from "../hooks/useCards";

const PlayingCard = () => {
  const { data } = useCards();

  //console.log(data[0]);

  return (
    <Card
      height="350px"
      width="250px"
      backgroundColor="rgba(228, 209, 188, 0.8)"
    >
      <CardBody>
        <Flex>
          <CardIcon />
          <Spacer />
          <CardIcon />
        </Flex>
        <Image padding="10px" fallbackSrc={placeholder}></Image>
      </CardBody>
      <CardFooter>
        <DescriptionText />
      </CardFooter>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default PlayingCard;
```

Here are my hooks and services:

```
import useData from "./useData";


export interface GauntletCard {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

const useCards = () => 
  useData<GauntletCard>('cards/?format=json');

export default useCards;'
```

```
'import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AxiosRequestConfig, CanceledError } from "axios";
import apiClient from "../services/api-client";
  
interface FetchReponse<T> {
    count: number;
    results: T[];
  }

const useData = <T>(endpoint: string, requestConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig, deps?: any[]) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<T[]>([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();

    setLoading(true);

    apiClient
      .get<FetchReponse<T>>(endpoint, {
        signal: controller.signal, ... requestConfig       })
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data.results);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err instanceof CanceledError) return;
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    return () => controller.abort();
  }, deps ? [...deps] : []);

  return { data, error, isLoading };
}

export default useData;
```

api-client.ts file:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/', // TEMP: development server
})
```

For the data variable in the PlayingCard Components, I am getting an empty array whereas the payload preview in the inspect tool shows the json object. This is why I am inclined towards the problem being in the frontend React Application. Also when I put the URL + enndpoint+ params in the browser, I see the beautiful JSON object.

Any help on how to approach the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Side Questions:

1. Does seeing the URL work in the browser immediately mean the problem is in the FrontEnd?
2. I am running React in StrictMode, which means I get 2 renders = 2 payloads. The first payload has the error "Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identiefier" but the second one has the JSON object. Does this have anything to do with the issue I am facing? OR is this normal?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

My endpoint is wrong: `cards/?format=json`
instead of `/cards?format=json`.